# NVD3 line chart - how can I add on-graph series labels?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a multi series line graph that I am adopting from an NVD3 sample.  The graph automatically includes a legend at the top showing the series names and colors (and selector to toggle on/off series).  I am trying to have the series labels appear at the end of each line instead of in the legend.  So the labels would essentially appear along the right y-axis at the point where each line terminates.
My code is pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure out where/how to insert some sort of .showLabels(true) method:

```
d3.json("linePlusBarData.json",function(error,data) {
 nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .y(function(d,i) {return d[1] });

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    chart.showLabels(true);


  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

nvd3.js is reusable charts, on-graph series labels are not supported by it. So you have to implement it by your own. Here is something like this on 3d.js

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/yr2Nw/4/][1]
```

Comment: Is there a way to just add this series labels using d3.js and still do the rest in NVD3 or are you saying I'd have to fully redo everything in D3.js natively and not use NVD3 at all?